# Adding to an environment variable still doesn't work

Tags: windows, emacs, path, environment-variables

I'm trying to get `emacs` to become a global name so I can reference it anywhere on my filesystem. This is what I did on the command line:

```
$PATH = C:/emacs/bin:$PATH
```

But when I do that I get the following error:

```
sh.exe": /c/home/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

I even went directly to <kbd>Start Menu</kbd>-><kbd>System [Properties]</kbd>-><kbd>Environment Variables</kbd> and I tried to add `C:\emacs\bin` to the list of the paths but the name still came up as `emacs: command not found`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Note that this is only a problem within `C:\cygwin`. Outside of that directory I can type `emacs` without a problem.

Comment: *"Can someone also explain why there are two?"* - One is user scope and one is system scope.  Is says so right there.

Comment: @EdS. OK. And also this is only happening within `C:\cygwin@`. Outside of that I am able to reference @`emacs` without a problem.

Comment: That I wish I had an answer for, but I have no idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command

```
$PATH = C:/emacs/bin:$PATH
```

has several problems:

1. `$` evaluates the variable, you need to set it
2. spaces are significant, you do not need them
3. you cannot use `:` inside a Cygwin path

Use this instead:

```
PATH=/c/emacs/bin:$PATH
```